# Why Postgres Replication Stream doesn't work when used in separate function?

Tags: java, postgresql, database-replication

I am working on postgres replication stream API. While working on it came across unusual behavior.

When I use replication slot writing whole code inside main block, everything works fine.

```
public class Server implements Config {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("prop")));

    String user = prop.getProperty("user");
    String password = prop.getProperty("password");
    String url = prop.getProperty("url");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    PGProperty.USER.set(props, user);
    PGProperty.PASSWORD.set(props, password);
    PGProperty.ASSUME_MIN_SERVER_VERSION.set(props, "9.4");
    PGProperty.REPLICATION.set(props, "database");
    PGProperty.PREFER_QUERY_MODE.set(props, "simple");

    Connection conn= null;
    PGConnection replicationConnection= null;
    PGReplicationStream stream = null;

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        replicationConnection = conn.unwrap(PGConnection.class);
        stream = replicationConnection.getReplicationAPI().replicationStream().logical()
                .withSlotName("replication_slot")
                .withSlotOption("include-xids", true)
                .withSlotOption("include-timestamp", "on")
                .withSlotOption("skip-empty-xacts", true)
                .withStatusInterval(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).start();

    while (true) {
            ByteBuffer msg;
            try {
                msg = stream.readPending();         

            if (msg == null) {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10L);
                continue;
            }

            int offset = msg.arrayOffset();
            byte[] source = msg.array();
            int length = source.length - offset;
            // convert byte buffer into string
            String data = new String(source, offset, length);

            // then convert it into bufferedreader
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(data));
            String line = reader.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            stream.setAppliedLSN(stream.getLastReceiveLSN());
            stream.setFlushedLSN(stream.getLastReceiveLSN());
        } catch (SQLException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
}
```

But when I try to separate stream logic using separate method like this

```
public class Server implements Config {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PGReplicationStream stream = getReplicationStream();
        while (true) {
            ByteBuffer msg;
            try {
                msg = stream.readPending();
    if (msg == null) {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10L);
                continue;
            }

            int offset = msg.arrayOffset();
            byte[] source = msg.array();
            int length = source.length - offset;
            String data = new String(source, offset, length);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(data));
            String line = reader.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            stream.setAppliedLSN(stream.getLastReceiveLSN());
            stream.setFlushedLSN(stream.getLastReceiveLSN());
        } catch (SQLException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

}
public static PGReplicationStream getReplicationStream() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        prop.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("prop")));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String user = prop.getProperty("user");
    String password = prop.getProperty("password");
    String url = prop.getProperty("url");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    PGProperty.USER.set(props, user);
    PGProperty.PASSWORD.set(props, password);
    PGProperty.ASSUME_MIN_SERVER_VERSION.set(props, "9.4");
    PGProperty.REPLICATION.set(props, "database");
    PGProperty.PREFER_QUERY_MODE.set(props, "simple");

    Connection conn= null;
    PGConnection replicationConnection= null;
    PGReplicationStream stream = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        replicationConnection = conn.unwrap(PGConnection.class);
        stream = replicationConnection.getReplicationAPI().replicationStream().logical()
                .withSlotName("replication_slot")
                .withSlotOption("include-xids", true)
                .withSlotOption("include-timestamp", "on")
                .withSlotOption("skip-empty-xacts", true)
                .withStatusInterval(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).start();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stream;
}
```

}

After reading some data, program is giving error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Database connection failed when reading from copy
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1028)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyDualImpl.readFromCopy(CopyDualImpl.java:41)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.receiveNextData(V3PGReplicationStream.java:155)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readInternal(V3PGReplicationStream.java:124)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readPending(V3PGReplicationStream.java:78)
at Server.main(Server.java:47)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:191)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receive(PGStream.java:495)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receive(PGStream.java:479)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processCopyResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1161)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1026)
... 5 more
```

I don't see any difference between both approach. But the program is behaving  differently. Can someone explain, what is wrong with second approach.

Comment: 1st application never crash ? you launched it multiple time with same duration as 2nd application ?    2nd application crash randomly? about always after running for ~5 minutes ?  or totally random time ?

Comment: Yes. 1st application never crash, even if I run it for 1 and half hours. 2nd application always crashes within running for 5 minutes.

Comment: Same parameter ? same driver ? (you're always so unlucky ? :D )

Comment: Ya, I didn't change anything. Just wanted to make code cleaner, so made different function to get the stream. When I got the error, I was debugging in other lines of code, never thought I could get error just by making separate function to get stream.

Comment: Consider making the question as short as possible, it is hard to read this tons of code

Comment: I just removed unnecessary lines and empty spaces from the question.

Comment: can't test it right now but if i had to bet i'd say it is related to the static declaration of PGReplicationStream

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem with with  `Connection`. It gets out of scope once your function returns and it is upto garbage collector to collect it and finalize. in finalize, connection is closed and probably then your program fails. Try moving connection and other required intermediate variables in a scope that is available in your main method and try again.

Answer (score 1):

There is some moderately bogus behavior with respect to closing a connection while doing a COPY. I wonder if that could be involved?

If memory serves, the issue was that a Terminate message (sent on Connection.close() to indicate that the client wants to end the
protocol connection) is *not* synchronized relative to COPY protocol operations. This means that *theoretically*, your Terminate message
could be shimmed right into the middle of a CopyData message. In practice, I've only ever seen an error from the server complaining
about an unexpected message type (Terminate) during COPY, since the client is *supposed* to send CopyDone or CopyFail before a Terminate
while a COPY is in effect. Still, I think it might be possible to get message contents munged.

I think your code *might* be susceptible to that since you kick off a bunch of COPY operations in a separate function and there might be a possibility that connection might get garbage collected.

As I see in the logs that socket connection is closed while copy protocol is still reading the data.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Database connection failed when reading from copy
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1028)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyDualImpl.readFromCopy(CopyDualImpl.java:41)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.receiveNextData(V3PGReplicationStream.java:155)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readInternal(V3PGReplicationStream.java:124)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readPending(V3PGReplicationStream.java:78)
at Server.main(Server.java:47)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
```