# Where can I find a complete list about replication slot options in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

I an working on PG logical replication by Java, and find a demo on the [jdbc driver docs](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/replication.html)

```
PGReplicationStream stream =
        replConnection.getReplicationAPI()
            .replicationStream()
            .logical()
            .withSlotName("demo_logical_slot")
            .withSlotOption("include-xids", false)
            .withSlotOption("skip-empty-xacts", true)
            .start();
```

then I can parse message from the stream.

This is enough for some daily needs, but now I want to know the transaction commit time.

From the help of [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572772/why-postgres-replication-stream-doesnt-work-when-used-in-separate-function) on stackoverflow, I add `.withSlotOption("include-timestamp", "on")` and it is working.

My question is where can find a complete list about the "slot option", so  we can find them very conveniently instead of search on google or stackoverflow.

Comment: A useful search phrase for your favorite search engine might be *postgresql slot option documentation*

Comment: As far as I know those options depend on the decoding plugin that the slot uses. It's not an option for the replication slot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The available options depend on the *logical decoding plugin* of the replication slot, which is specified when the replication slot is created.

The example must be using the [`test_decoding`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/test-decoding.html) plugin, which is included with PostgreSQL as a contrib module for testing and playing.

The available options for that plugin are not documented, but can be found in the [source code](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=contrib/test_decoding/test_decoding.c;hb=HEAD):

- `include-xids`: include the transaction number in `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` output
- `include-timestamp`: include timestamp information with `COMMIT` output
- `force-binary`: specifies that the [output mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding-output-plugin.html#LOGICALDECODING-OUTPUT-MODE) is binary
- `skip-empty-xacts`: don't output anything for transactions that didn't modify the database
- `only-local`: output only data whose [replication origin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/replication-origins.html) is not set
- `include-rewrites`: include information from table rewrites caused by DDL statements